# RxJava - subcribe and wait until a variable is true

Tags: android, rx-java

I've searched but found nothing so far... or I'm just confuse what should I look for.

What I'm trying to do is, a subscription will be made and will check if variable X is TRUE. If not it will wait until it turns to TRUE and execute the succeeding events.

I'm looking into the repeat() method but not sure how it works... any suggestion is very much appreciated...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just emit your variable in a observable, and `filter` it. You can use a `PublishSubject` to emit your variable.

```
 PublishSubject<Boolean> subject = PublishSubject.create();


 void updateBoolean(boolean b) {
      subject.onNext(b);
 }


 // latter in your code
 subject.filter(b -> b)
        .subscribe(b -> /* do something here only if b is true */);
```